# Are there other ways to graph a zigzag line?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, sequence-of-function

I teach precalculus and I was addressing a common misconception that students have when I came across something puzzling to me. When we graph $\sin^{-1}(\sin(x))$ and $\cos^{-1}(\cos(x))$ we get a zigzag line as the graph. Are there other ways that do not involve piecewise functions to get a zigzag line with finitely many bumps, or a different formula that gives infinitely many bumps?

For the finite question, I can think of using nested absolute values to get finitely many bumps with the sequence of functions $f_0(x) = |x|, f_n(x) = |1-f_{n-1}(x)|$, where $f_n$ has $n$ bumps. This is where my ideas dry up. I can't seem to find another method that gives similar results for finite bumps and I don't know where to start for infinite bumps.

Comment: There might be a general form but there's also a Fourier series that gives you zig zags. $\frac{\sin{x}}{1} + \frac{\sin{2x}}{2} + \frac{\sin{3x}}{3} +... + \frac{\sin{kx}}{k} = \sum_{n = 1}^{k}{\frac{\sin{kx}}{k}}$

Comment: If I haven't made a mistake: Let $~\displaystyle \lfloor x\rfloor ~$ denote the *floor* of $~x.~$  Then, consider the function $$f(x) = (-1)^{\lfloor x\rfloor} \times \left( ~x - \lfloor x\rfloor - \frac{1}{2} ~\right).$$  Characterizing the floor function as a *step* function would invalidate the example.  Alternatively, if *step* function represents a *piecemeal* definition, then $~f(x)~$ avoids that.

Comment: Woah! I didn't think about using the floor function. Very interesting strategy to get infinitely many waves.